# umbraco 4.8.1 node icon always shows "unpublished" icon

Tags: umbraco

In umbraco 4.8.1.

When i click "save and publish" button for a node, the popup box in right bottom shows publish successfully, but the node icon still shows the "unpublished" icon.

Any help on this ?

In my node, i use some multi-node tree picker data type as my fields.

Thanks

Comment: resolved by upgrading umbraco to version 4.9.0

Comment: you can also "reload nodes" to see the new real status if you're still in 4.8.1 (it's curiousm the node status is refresh if you unpublish, but not if you publish)

Comment: please: edit your question to include "RESOLVED" in the title, and the answer in the question text.

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue but with 4.9.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this will be of use to you, but take a look at this bug issue. It might be the reason. It deals with Umbraco 4.7, but it looks like this issue is present in later versions as well.

http://issues.umbraco.org/issue/U4-387